# Free Metric Space?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, category-theory

Do free metric spaces exist?
Ie.: An object in the category of metric spaces and lipschitzian maps.

If so would these be the complete metric spaces, since they satisfy a similar universal property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The free metric space on one element exists, of course. And since you are considering Lipschitz maps, it is easy to verify that the space with $n$ points and the discrete metric is freely generated by its points, when $n$ is finite. If $n$ is infinite then we have a problem: if such a metric space $X$ existed, then we would be able to construct a Lipschitz map $X \to \mathbb{R}$ where the image of the generating set is unbounded – a contradiction, since the distance between any two generating points in $X$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks, this is also an intereseting example of why Met is not cocomplete :D